# Remove/Kill Wasps When You Cannot Get to the Nest

Tags: pest-control

Advice on how to get rid of wasps now in the cold months. Last Summer I had a terrible infestation of wasps underneath a plastic utility shed with a wooden foundation. They were getting in from a hole or holes in the foundation. I was unable to reach or see a nest. I sprayed a couple of dozen cans of insecticide around the holes (different brands, saturate them and it appeared to have little to no effect on them). I sprayed winterizing (orange colored) foam all around the foundation in hopes of preventing egress. Either a small area was missed or they worked their way out. So, short of disassembling the shed and building a new foundation (cinder blocks would be a good but costly solution). Any solutions that have proven to repel wasps etc to insure they will not return? I had a nest in the soffit of the house and was able to knock it down in the Winter. Hopefully, they will not return from that location - or will they? BTW they never bothered anyone from that location. The wasps under the shed were murderous. Thank you!

---

[image: I have looked at traps. Even found easy plans for making them with liter pop bottles. The problem I have with traps going into the Spring is traps will attract wasps to the backyard.I would like to avoid them ever being on my property.]
I have uploaded an image of where I believe the primary place the wasps are entering the shed. The foam evenly covered the holes when it was first applied. However, the weather has done a job on it. 
The shed is usable as it is. Would really like to avoid disassembling the shed and building a new foundation. Spray cans won't reach. Appreciate any ideas.

Comment: A picture of the utility shed might help us offer ideas.

Comment: I am allergic and have tried everything in a few cases most after sunset when they are home. One case similar to yours I sealed all the outside walls of a tool shed and ran a small gas motor exhaust under the shed. The first time I did it at night. The CO carbon monoxide may have killed some but the second time I added a little 2 stroke oil to the fuel and did it before sunrise. That took them out , Had a few a couple months or so later maybe baby's? Or newcomers. Used the same motor and a bit of 2 stroke oil in the gas and they have not returned. ( it has been 2+ years)

Comment: Please use the [edit] link underneath your post if you want to add extra information.

Answer (score 1):

## Have you thought about using a trap?

We had an infestation of yellow jackets last fall, and tried almost everything to wipe them out after my brother got stung by a swarm while out mowing the lawn, only we couldn't find the nests. What we ended up doing was hanging a trap in the back yard, and only a few days later, we started catching the little buggers in it.

The trap we bought, called a "Rescue W.H.Y" trap (make sure to grab attractant refills too), supposedly works on wasps and hornets, but I can definitely say that it works on yellow jackets. You can find them in the Garden section of a local Home Depot or Lowe's, but it's a little cheaper online, if you don't mind waiting a few days to get them.

Hope this helps!